# Why do I need branches tracking

Tags: git

I create a local branch and I want to share it with my programming partner on the remote repository. We want to work on that branch for a while, before we finish the project and merge to the master.

Is there any problem with this (I start at my 'master'):

```
git checkout -b BRANCH
git commit -am "changes"
git push
```

He can pull the branch from the remote, right?
When he push updates I can 'git pull' (when being checked in the BRANCH), am I right?

Why/When do I need to set tracking. Can I pull/push from the BRANCH without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workflow sounds completely OK to me, and is a typical workflow used by GitHub and a few of the other providers.

With regard to your confusion about having to set tracking, note that you created your branch using this:

```
git checkout -b BRANCH      # on some other branch
```

You could have *also* created the same branch using this:

```
git branch --track BRANCH origin/BRANCH
```

In this alternative method of creating a branch, we explicitly tell Git that we want the local branch `BRANCH` to track the remote branch also called `BRANCH`.  But doing it using your method, the tracking is set automatically, and we don't need to worry about it.

Using either method, our local branch `BRANCH` is setup to point to the correct branch in the remote, so pulling and pushing should work with no issues.

Comment: By 'checkout -b BRANCH' git somehow knows the correct tracking? Even without any new lines in config specifying it?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm telling you.  Git will default to track a remote branch called `BRANCH`.  Most of the time, this isn't an issue.  It's only a problem when you want to track a remote branch with a different name.

Comment: Thank you. Can I have different question? When my coworker wants to checkout my new `BRANCH`. All answers tell to `git fetch origin` and `git checkout BRANCH` as the simpliest approach, right? But we usually do `git pull` on master and that's all. Can he ckeckout this new `BRANCH` with a single command after he does the usuall `git pull` on master?

Comment: I think you need more than one command to do this.  But once you have the local branch, many operations can be one-liners.

Comment: So, I can't do `git pull` followed by `git checkout BRANCH` to checkout new `BRANCH` from the remote? I need to do `git fetch` instead of pull, do I understand?

Comment: You are confused about the basics in Git, because your question does not make sense.  If a local branch does not already exist, you wouldn't be doing a `git pull` at all, you would `git fetch`.

Comment: So, when someone needs to update master branch and also checkout new coworkers branch -> he needs to (as one of the options): `git pull` `git fetch` `git checkout BRANCH`, right?

Comment: No...from the `master` branch he could do `git pull origin master` followed by `git branch --track BRANCH origin/BRANCH`

Comment: I think part of the confusion comes from the fact that [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) performs a `git fetch` and afterwards a `git merge`. `pull` is really two commands wrapped into one. So after doing a `git pull` you can start tracking (checking out) branches from the remote that you previously did not have on your local machine.

Comment: Because I know that `git pull` does fetch+merge, I was interested why I can't checkout new remote branch with `git pull` `git checkout BRANCH` as I would do with `git fetch` `git checkout BRANCH`. Still don't understand exactly.

Comment: Neither `pull` nor `fetch` will actually _create_ a local branch, it will only create a new _tracking_ branch, possibly, if a new one has appeared since your last pulled/fetched.

Comment: Hm, I am not saying that I want to create local branch with pull or fetch. I am trying to understand, what's the difference between creating (checking) local branch after `pull` or `fetch`. All tutorials say to `git fetch` and then `git checkout branch`. I would like to understand, if I can (or why I can't) do `git pull` and then `git checkout branch`. If the `pull` is doing `fetch` anyway.

Comment: I am talking about this case (copied from the https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches):

In fact, this is so common that there’s even a shortcut for that shortcut. If the branch name you’re trying to checkout (a) doesn’t exist and (b) exactly matches a name on only one remote, Git will create a tracking branch for you:
$ git checkout serverfix

Comment: I never knew this, you just caused me to learn something.  Then yes, `git fetch origin` followed by `git checkout BRANCH` should do it.

Comment: Ok :) I know that `fetch` can be followed by `checkout` in this case. But can the `fetch` be replaced with `pull` and followed by the same `checkout`? That's what I am trying to find out.

Comment: Yes, because `git pull` is just a `git fetch` followed by a merge for that branch.